# pipedrive update deal with put/post request with using php, curl and REST

Tags: php, rest, api, curl, pipedrive-api

I'm trying to update a deal in pipedrive CRM using the API. What I'm trying to do is to update the owner of a deal to a new user. But this is not successful.

[docs](https://developers.pipedrive.com/v1)

Here is my code:

```
$deal_id = 31811; //the id of the add that i want to update

$deal = array(
    "user_id" => 1858654, //the id of the user that will be the new owner
    "stage_id" => 1 //the stage id where the deal should be
);

$api_token = "x";
$url = "https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/".$deal_id."?api_token=" . $api_token;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $deal);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the returned error.

```
array (
  'url' => 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals/31811?api_token=X',
  'content_type' => NULL,
  'http_code' => 0,
  'header_size' => 0,
  'request_size' => 0,
  'filetime' => -1,
  'ssl_verify_result' => 1,
  'redirect_count' => 0,
  'total_time' => 0.32900000000000001,
  'namelookup_time' => 0,
  'connect_time' => 0.157,
  'pretransfer_time' => 0,
  'size_upload' => 0,
  'size_download' => 0,
  'speed_download' => 0,
  'speed_upload' => 0,
  'download_content_length' => -1,
  'upload_content_length' => -1,
  'starttransfer_time' => 0,
  'redirect_time' => 0,
  'redirect_url' => '',
  'primary_ip' => 'x.x.x.x',
  'certinfo' => 
  array (
  ),
  'primary_port' => x,
  'local_ip' => 'x.x.x.x',
  'local_port' => x,
)error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info:
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: There is no 'stage_id' parameter in docs.

Comment: @Gowri on PUT Update a deal/deals/:id there is a field called stage_id

Comment: @Tom this do not return any error.

Comment: Can you try `print_r($output)`. What  response comes from api.

Comment: @Gowri i do not get any result at all. It returns false

Comment: Have you tried the endpoint calling using "Tryit" option in developers site. Using your api access key.

Comment: I'm having the same issues, I think it may be a bug in the API.  I can add deals, but not edit them.  I'll ask PipeDrive.

Comment: @AndyGaskell If I remember correctly this error occured because cURL was not activated on my WAMP server. Here is a link to my thread that solved the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401608/php-7-0-curl-not-working-wamp-on-windows-10-64-bit

Comment: @EdvardÅkerberg thanks for the reply, I think that's not the solution in my case unfortunately. I'm using php7, but on Linux, also, many other API calls work ok, it seems I just can't edit deals.  Using your code above, just change the api key, deal id and user id, I get "{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method ."}".  Did the above code work for you once you activated cURL?

Comment: I found the problem in my code, which is also in the above example.  Using POST doesn't work, it has to be PUT.  My fault, as it does say in the API docs.