# PHP 7.0 cURL not working - WAMP on Windows 10 64 bit

Tags: php, curl, wamp, windows-10, php-7

cURL is not working when I run curl on my WAMP server. Anyone know how to activate this for php 7.0+?

I have tried to uncomment extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini

Here is my error message:

```
cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Comment: "it's not working" is not a valid description of any problem.

Comment: did you restart everything after making that change?

Comment: ...did you "Google" that error? Many hits found. @EdvardÅkerberg

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes i have restarted the server, it's something else that is wrong. I  ran the same code on my real web server and the curls works like it is supposed to. It's only when I run it from my WAMP server.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes i have googled the errror, there are solutions for PHP version 5.4 and lower but not for PHP 7

Comment: I see. I had a similar problem before but on 5.6 and on Windows 7, so am unsure how to help you out any further, without having to keep on Googling. Wait for others who may know something I don't. @EdvardÅkerberg

Comment: You have ca-bundle.crt in your installation ? Is it correctly configured in your php.ini file, on curl.cainfo and openssl.cafile options ?

Comment: @old_mountain I can't find any file in my installation thats called ca-bundle.crt. Is there a guide on how to install it?

Comment: See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858351/php-ssl-certificate-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate/32095378#32095378

Comment: @old_mountain it works!

Answer (score 15):

1. Download ca-bundle.crt from https://github.com/bagder/ca-bundle/blob/e9175fec5d0c4d42de24ed6d84a06d504d5e5a09/ca-bundle.crt
2. Put the file in c:\wamp64\
3. Change php.ini to the following

   curl.cainfo="C:/wamp64/ca-bundle.crt"

   openssl.cafile="C:/wamp64/ca-bundle.crt"

This worked for me.

**Note :** You have to restart server after doing above process.

Comment: Thanks, this saved me, after numerous searches and hours spending to find solution. This worked.

Comment: Thank you.  A few hours of searching.
For others searching:
Windows WAMP apache php curl not working no error messages curl is enabled.
I used the latest cacert.pem from https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html